# C++ inhereting enclosing class - is this good practice?

Tags: c++, class, oop, inheritance, nested

I've recently tried to design parts of my code in modules. My problem was how to name it and keep it so that name/adress to class would be both easy and told everything there is to know about class' purpose. First idea was to create interface (abstract class) named **Foo** and then in namespace **Foo** create classes, so that i would have code like:

```
Foo* foo = Foo::Bar();
```

but we can't create both namespace and class with same name. So another approach was to make interface as enclosing class and put specified class (their declarations) inside it, and later on define those specified classes:

```
class A {
    public:
        void foo() = 0;

        class B;
        class C;
};

class B : public A {
    //
};

class C : public A {
    //
};
```

I'm wondering if this kind of desing for classes and interfaces is good practice? Or should i use something else/never mind bad naming for base class?

Big **pro** is naming. If - for example - i use it as exception system - I can write code like this:

```
Exception* exception = new Exception::IllegalArgument();
```

instead of:

```
Exception::Interface* exception = new Exception::IllegalArgument();
```

But there is also big **con** i've noticed. I can write something like:

```
Exception::IllegalArgument::Exception::IllegalArgument::Exce... exception;
```

So, what do you think about that? Is it okey and nver-mind that endless loop with types, or i should think about different strategy?

Answer (score 0):

It's indifferent practice.

With that I mean that it neither buys you all that much, nor are there really disadvantages.

Still, the norm is just putting them together in the same namespace and be done with it.

It "looks cleaner", and if you change the hierarchy there's at least a chance you'll get it done without too much bloodshed.

Comment: Okey, so beside creating one namespace and throw everything related in there, could you recommend other desing patterns for something like that (one base class and many derived classes? or even some hierarchy)?